# Discrepancy between CV review queue history and all actions on profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, review-history

If I look on my profile on the all actions tab and look at the CV review tasks I see what action I took on what post. This however doesn't show the current status of the questions, like `[closed]` or `[on hold]`.

[image]

If I go to the review history tab the URL's are updated with their current status. Where did this discrepancy arise from?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to display question status in the profile page, or are you just curious about the reason? Because the first one is a `feature-request`, the second one is not very useful, IMO.

Comment: @Yivi it just struck me as odd. As both hyperlinks point in the same direction. I didn't see the reason why the status shouldn't be displayed on the profile page. Perhaps it could also be a bug? It would be nice to have on the profile page, but making it a full-fledged feature request is kinda pointless imho seeing the massive load of more usefull requests out there that are still waiting for 6-8 developers to have time to do something with them. Hence just a discussion tag.